# Songs which have relations or parts of other songs

Tags: terminology

I'm currently searching for songs which have older songs in it part-wise. I don't even know what this term is called. I'm thinking of something like Eminem's *Sing for the Moment* which contains parts of Aerosmith's *Dream On*.

Comment: Are you trying to find out the terminology for that or a certain sample within a song? If you're trying to find a sample within the song, what is the song's name, when does this sample occur?

Comment: I'm tryn to find out the terminology how this is called when a surctain sample is played within a song. And i'm tryn to find such songs I only this one.

Comment: The website [whosampled](https://www.whosampled.com/) lists every registered song that has a sample and its original.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for coming in, but I had to request closure for your question since it is not clear exactly what you are asking... if you want a complete list of all the songs in the world that sample another song it would be too huge!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a name for a song(s) within a song?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/6557/is-there-a-name-for-a-songs-within-a-song)

Comment: @ChrisSunami That link talks about interpolation, not sampling. The two seem to be different: http://help.songtrust.com/licensing-and-sync/samples/what-is-the-difference-between-a-sample-and-interpolation Also: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/5834/what-is-the-difference-between-samples-interpolations-elements-and-portions

Comment: I'm not 100% convinced Kevin is interested in sampling rather than interpolation...

Comment: @ChrisSunami I see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term you're looking for is probably [sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(music)). To quote from Wikipedia, sampling is

> **the reuse of a portion or sample of a sound recording in another recording**. Samples may comprise rhythm, melody, speech, or other sounds.

As for examples, you can try searching on Google using keywords like 'list of sampled songs' or the like. There are a lot of these songs and it would require an extremely long list if I put it here.

Edit: As mentioned by @Bebs, you can also try checking out [whosampled](https://www.whosampled.com). This lists songs and the samples used or if they were sampled or covered in other songs.

Comment: ah well this helps quite a lot to search these kind of songs. I know that "coverd songs" are the "same song" from another interpret. But is there a mix in between. Like if the song is half "coverd" but with own supplements. Is this considerd a sample or cover ?

Comment: @Kevin As far as I know, that's still a whole new song which samples another one. In the Wikipedia entry of your example, it was stated that Eminem's song samples Dream On, not cover. I guess it does not matter how much of a song is sampled as long as it's not the whole song (this would be a cover if that were the case). Another example would be Flo Rida's Right Round which samples Dead or Alive's You Spin Me Round (Like a Record).

Comment: @Kevin I also advise checking out the link given by a user above as I think you'll find that quite useful, too.